# How does Speed control in BLDC motor work?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

I am trying to run two BLDC motors rated 48V 2000W using a 48V 110Ah battery pack by connecting the motors in parallel (hub motor for EV application). The motors are individually connected to separate controllers and speed control is done with a single potentiometer throttle (connected to both the controllers).
So when the throttle is pressed, voltage applied to motors increases, so the speed increases. But what I am unable to understand is, how does the current and power drawn by the motor vary when I keep increasing the speed ?

Comment: The simplest version of speed control is to adjust the duty cycle from 0 to 100% as the throttle voltage goes from 0 to the max.

Comment: Depends on the load applied to the motors.

Comment: Are the motor shafts connected together mechanically? If so, it will be important to make sure the controllers somehow drive them equally. If there is anything unequal between the two controllers, some kind of series resistance or whatever, one of them may so all the work. My thinking is that slightly fancier controllers capable of torque control will share more equally (if they are operated in torque output mode).